# Form change and validity in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-validation

Whenever any non-readonly input in my form changes and the form is valid, I want to do certain action. Let's say, my form looks like

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
    <input ng-model='input.a' required/>
    <input ng-model='input.b' required/>
    <input value='{{output.p | number: 2}}' readonly/>
    <input value='{{output.q | number: 2}}' readonly/>
</form>
```

Now upon any change of `input`, I want to do something, whenever `input.a` and `input.b` are valid. I tried `$watch(input)`, but it didn't work. Watching all its members does, but it feels stupid. Adding `ng-change` to all fields feels better, but still pretty stupid (non-DRY). What's the proper way?

---

The other question is how to find out if the input is valid. If I had a button, I could do simply

```
<button ng-click="doIt()" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">
```

but how can I access `form.$invalid` in the controller (it's not contained in `$scope`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access `form.$invalid` by doing

```
$scope.form.$invalid
```

See here: [AngularJs can't access form object in controller ($scope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574472/angularjs-cant-access-form-object-in-controller-scope)

To watch for changes in the form, you should be able to do:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('input')
```

Comment: Both work, thx a lot. But according to your link it should work for me without any `setFormScope` (I'm not doing `$modal.open` not anything like this; just a basic page with a basic ctrl), but it doesn't. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

@dave has already answered your first question, but for the second I have a solution that I consider more elegant:

In your controller you have declare an object, for example:

```
$scope.forms = {};
```

Then you form name must be nested inside that object:

```
<form name="forms.someForm">
    ...
```

Finally in your controller you can do things like this:

```
if($scope.forms.someForm.$invalid) {
    ...
}
```