# Form is undefined in scope in Angular 1.3

Tags: angularjs

I don't if this is something I did, but once I upgraded to Angular 1.3, the form is no longer defined in my scope. My HTML is

```
<div some-dir>

    <form name="myForm">
    <!-- Form stuff here -->
    <button ng-click="submit();">
    </form>

</div>
```

The `submit` function is

```
scope.submit = function() {
    console.log(scope.myForm);
}
```

And this returns undefined. I have no `ng-if` or `ng-repeat` anywhere. There is only one directive and one scope in this specific directive. Again, this was all working until I upgraded to Angular 1.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem can be solved by scoping form data into some scope object:

```
  <form name="myForms.firstForm">
    <!-- Form stuff here -->
    <button ng-click="submit();">
  </form>
```

And than:

```
scope.myForms = {};
scope.submit = function() {
    console.log(scope.myForms.firstForm);
}
```

Some more info in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574472/angularjs-cant-access-form-object-in-controller-scope#comment32589645_21574537).

Comment: Great tip! By upgrading from 1.2 to 1.4 I lost my form in the controller. Because I use AngularUI in version 0.8.0 (still stuck to Bootstrap 2.3.2) every other solution I found on the web was unsatisfactory.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution that works. It's a shame to have to resort to such hackery just to get something so basic and fundamental in AngularJS to work as you'd reasonably expect it to.I love AngularJS except when I have to do stuff like this. :/

Answer (score 2):

In my case it happened that my *form* was nested within another *form*.
So once I switched the `<form name="myForm">` to `<ng-form name="myForm" ...>` the form was defined.

See [ng-form docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm).

Comment: For me, nothing else worked but this. I tried watch, parent scoping, etc.

Comment: Same! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem and fixed by declaring the controller in the html template that contains the form. So you form declaration would become:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="SomeController">
```

New "feature" of 1.3, probably..