# TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined` in the following code where I try to execute `inputCtrl.inputForm.$setPristine();`

inputForm.js

```
(function(){
    var inputForm = angular.module('input-form', [ ]);

    inputForm.directive('inputForm', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'input-form.html',
            scope: {data: "="},
            controllerAs: 'inputCtrl',
            bindToController: true,
            controller: ['$log', '$scope', function($log, $scope){
              var inputCtrl = this;
              inputCtrl.inputValues = millennialsDefault;

              inputCtrl.emitData = function() {
                inputCtrl.data =  inputCtrl.inputValues.topic1Data;

                $log.debug("Emitting '" + 
                        inputCtrl.inputValues.topic1Name + "' to '" + 
                        inputCtrl.inputValues.topic2Name + "'");
              };

              inputCtrl.swapInput = function(){
                  var swappedInputValues = {
                          topic1Name: inputCtrl.inputValues.topic2Name,
                          topic1Total: inputCtrl.inputValues.topic2Total,
                          topic1Data: inputCtrl.inputValues.topic2Data,
                          topic2Name: inputCtrl.inputValues.topic1Name,
                          topic2Total: inputCtrl.inputValues.topic1Total,
                          topic2Data: inputCtrl.inputValues.topic1Data,
                  };

                  inputCtrl.inputValues = swappedInputValues;
              };

              inputCtrl.clearInput = function(){
                  inputCtrl.inputValues = 
                  {
                          topic1Name: "",
                          topic1Total: undefined,
                          topic1Data: "",
                          topic2Name: "",
                          topic2Total: undefined,
                          topic2Data: "",
                  };
                  inputCtrl.inputForm.$setPristine(); // TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the solution is to change `inputCtrl.inputForm.$setPristine();` to `$scope.inputForm.$setPristine();`.

Here are some references:

- [Can I access a form in the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568761/can-i-access-a-form-in-the-controller)
- [Angular: Should I use this or $scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619740/angular-should-i-use-this-or-scope)
- [AngularJs can't access form object in controller ($scope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574472/angularjs-cant-access-form-object-in-controller-scope)

If you prefer to use `this` and avoid referencing `$scope` then this might be a solution: http://www.technofattie.com/2014/07/01/using-angular-forms-with-controller-as-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

check for any open function calls which is rendering the page before the form creation which may end-up in " $setPristine is undefined "

for example in your controller

```
    $scope.reset= function(form){
        form.$setPristine();
    };
   $scope.reset();
```

if there is something like this you can see that error ,
While loading itself it will engage the $setPristine();

Comment: while this can indeed occur, I don't think this really applies to the situation that was present in this question.  Also, this question was posted and then answered a ***more than a year ago*** by the poster themselves, so it is unlikely that they are still looking for a viable answer.