# Having trouble accessing form from Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs

When trying to access a form field's $valid property from inside the controller, I get "cannot access $valid of undefined."  Here's what I've tried, based on other answers on SO, to no avail:

1. Use controllerAs - I was already using controllerAs in my route but for good measure I added an ng-controller="TestCtrl as testCtrl" to my container DIV.
2. Try ng-init, passing the scope - I added an ng-init to the form tag (ng-init=testFunction(this) that calls a controller function to set a property on the scope called formScope (as seen here: [AngularJs can't access form object in controller ($scope)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574472/angularjs-cant-access-form-object-in-controller-scope))
3. Try scope = {} in your controller
4. Several other suggestions that I fail to remember right now.

My requirements are, to me, simple:
When the field loads (controller loads the model data), we need to:

1. Show the appropriate validation glyphicon next to the field.
2. When the field's validity changes, the glyphicon needs to change accordingly
3. Icons: 
   when $valid = false, use glyphicon-remove 
    when $valid = true, use glyphicon-ok
   when $valid = null or undefined (possible?), use glyphicon-warning-sign
4. Be able to pass the validity to a directive (future use)

See the following plunk:  https://embed.plnkr.co/XXFM6Mtt1KnSci5yagTd/

Any help or different approaches is appreciated.  This is kicking my butt.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
self.sexValid = testForm.sex.$valid;
```

by

```
self.sexValid = self.testForm.sex.$valid;
```

That said, why duplicate that information in a field of the controller, instead of simply using

```
testCtrl.testForm.sex.$valid
```

directly in the view?

Comment: Good point.  Overthinking the problem I guess.  I appreciate the help - I tried it in my real app and it works there too.  Thanks so much.